# Can copyright be made on to a specific word or name?

Tags: copyright, trademark

I wanted to use two words 'HAKAI' and 'BEERUS SAMA' in my design but when i posted them the site took it down and said it has been ended early due to content concern. What is the actual issue here? why i cant use them? and if not how i can be sure not using such words again? where i an check these?

Answer (score 0):

### The terms can't be covered by copyright

Single words and names are not copyrightable [as the US Copyright Office explains](https://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-protect.html#title) and has a [specific information paper about](https://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ33.pdf):

> #### Can I copyright the name of my band?
>
> **No.** Names are not protected by copyright law. Some names may be protected under trademark law. Contact the [U.S. Patent & Trademark Office](http://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/support-centers/trademark-assistance-center-tac), TrademarkAssistanceCenter@uspto.gov or see [Circular 33](https://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ33.pdf) "Copyright Protection Not Available for Names, Titles, or Short Phrases".
>
> #### How do I copyright a name, title, slogan, or logo?
>
> **Copyright does not protect names**, titles, slogans, **or short phrases**. In some cases, these things may be protected as trademarks. Contact the [U.S. Patent & Trademark Office](http://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/support-centers/trademark-assistance-center-tac), TrademarkAssistanceCenter@uspto.gov or see [Circular 33](https://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ33.pdf), for further information. However, copyright protection may be available for logo artwork that contains sufficient authorship. In some circumstances, an artistic logo may also be protected as a trademark.

> #### Names, Titles, Short Phrases
>
> Words and short phrases, such as names, titles, and slogans, are uncopyrightable because they contain
> an insufficient amount of authorship. The Office will not register individual words or brief combinations of words, even if the word or short phrase is novel, distinctive, or lends itself to a play on words.
> Examples of names, titles, or short phrases that do not contain a sufficient amount of creativity
> to support a claim in copyright include
> Works Not Protected by Copyright 3
>
> - The name of an individual (including pseudonyms, pen names, or stage names)
> - The title or subtitle of a work, such as a book, a song, or a pictorial, graphic, or sculptural work
> - The name of a business or organization
> - The name of a band or performing group
> - The name of a product or service
> - A domain name or URL
> - The name of a character
> - Catchwords or catchphrases
> - Mottos, slogans, or other short expressions
>
> Under certain circumstances, names, titles, or short phrases may be protectable under federal or
> state trademark laws. For information about trademark laws, visit the U.S. Patent and Trademark
> Office website or call 1-800-786-9199.

### Content on sites is only regulated by the hoster

The terms of service and acceptable use policy of the hosting company dictate what sort of content you may host on their site. That is contract law. You need to inquire into your contract with the hosting company and the associated documents (ToS, Acceptable use policy, community guidelines etc.) to understand their moderation decision. However, websites have in those contracts an enshrined nigh limitless allowance to moderate and take down content for any or no reason.